# Dados customizados no full calendar jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Preciso carregar dados customizados no `full calendar jquery`, como por exemplo o `id` daquele evento.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
title: '{{$reuniao->TXT_TEMAX_REUNI}}',
start: '{{$reuniao->getStart}}',
allDay: true,
id: '{{$reuniao->COD_IDENT_REUNI}}'
className: 'bgm-cyan'
```

Para plotar no calendario porém ele não o faz. Preciso fazer isto para quando clicar eu consiga enviar para página devida da reunião.

Comment: `$reuniao` vem do php?

Comment: Sabe, cara, esse é um jeito horrível de pegar constantes (ou variáveis) de uma classe. Construa um método.

Comment: sim é PHP, e utilizando laravel, o erro não esta no titulo, está em id

Comment: descobri o meu erro :\

Comment: Na linha do id falta uma ',' no final, assim acarretando o erro :D

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei meu erro, estava no final da linha do `id` falta uma `,` então a resolução foi:

```
title: '{{$reuniao->TXT_TEMAX_REUNI}}',
start: '{{$reuniao->getStart}}',
allDay: true,
id: '{{$reuniao->COD_IDENT_REUNI}}',
className: 'bgm-cyan'
```

Comment: Esqueceu de adicionar a vírgula no final da linha novamente =)